# java TimerTask example

Tags: java, timertask

I need to execute a thread at a regular interval of time. I am using timerTask method in my java program

```
public class StudentDTO  extends  TimerTask{
@Override
public void run(){  
    System.out.println("hi");
}
        public static void main(String[] args){ 

    StudentDTO t1=new StudentDTO();  
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(t1, 0, 10000);
    System.out.println("start");

     try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

}

when i executed this code,I got answer like

start
hi
hi

and the program will get terminated.
I have to run a thread at each 10 sec.Please suggest me a solution

Comment: `Timer timer = new Timer(true);` - why true?

Comment: I got that code from google

Comment: read my answer to understand why you should try to understand the code you find :-)

Comment: Can I use this TimerTask to call a normal method at a regular interval of time?

Comment: Not any arbitrary `method` You can use it to invoke tasks at ctertain times.  I would actually recommend  that you look at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

So change to

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
```

This will create a user Thread

Comment: Can I use this TimerTask to call a normal method at a regular interval of time?

Comment: see my comment above

Answer (score 1):

Change `new Timer(true)` to `new Timer()` otherwise it's a daemon thread and application dies when main exits

Comment: Can I use this TimerTask to call a normal method at a regular interval of time?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can make your program run every 10 seconds.

1. Timer timer=new Timer();
2. By changing the time you have for thread to sleep. It should be more than or equal to the interval you want to schedule your task.For Instance,

   ```
           try {
               Thread.sleep(12000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
   ```